# Unable to print python thread name

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print the default thread name for the timer thread, but that is printing nothing, please let me know what is wrong I have done.

```
from threading import current_thread, Timer,Thread
def def1():
    print "inside def1 method",current_thread()

timer1 = Timer(0,def1, [])
timer1.setDaemon(True)
timer1.start()
```

and output is

```
inside def1 method
```

why above code is not printing the thread name, please let me know. I am using python 2.7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timer1` is a daemon thread. The most likely cause is that it gets killed (by your process terminating) before it gets a chance to print the result of `current_thread()`.

Try joining the thread to see if it makes a difference (it does for me):

```
from threading import current_thread, Timer,Thread

def def1():
    print "inside def1 method",current_thread()

timer1 = Timer(0,def1, [])
timer1.setDaemon(True)
timer1.start()
timer1.join()  # <====== ADD THIS
```